# What is the term for off limits to foreigners?

Tags: english-to-japanese

There are certain establishments that are exclusively Japanese only. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very few times I've seen it it's been one of the following:

外国人の入店お断り
   Foreigners entry into store is refused

外国人お断り
   Foreigners refused

Both are written in a formal way. Longer more formal versions also exist, but with the same basic format, such as:

外国人の方の入場をお断り致します
   Foreigners refused entry into this establishment